# Prove that every finite integral domain is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation

I am a little confused about the proof for the following theorem:

> Every finite integral domain is a field.

$R$ is a finite integral domain with $R^{*}$ being the set of nonzero elements of $R$. The proof defines a map for all $a\in R^{*}$ to be $\lambda_{a}(r)=ar$ for $r\in R^{*}$. It showed it was injective. Then this is the part I am confused about: Since $R^{*}$ is a subset of $R$, $R^{*}$ is finite hence must be surjective. Could someone please explain this implication?

Comment: An injective self map $F \to F$ for any finite set $F$ must also be surjective.  Since it is surjective in your case, $1 \in R^*$ is hit.

Comment: Oh, I did not know this! Thank you for clearing it up for me.

Comment: Explained at almost every duplicate.